# Gravitational lensing, indices of refraction and the size of the universe

Tags: cosmology, refraction, gravitational-lensing

Been pondering the following question for over 15 years now.

Is it possible that the size of the universe has been over estimated due to the effects of gravitational lensing and boundary indices of refraction causing observers to view the same galaxies multiple times at various times in the past? Boundaries like the cosmic web or differences between matter/energy densities.

Comment: Boundary of what?

Comment: Have you seen [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0310808) by Davis & Lineweaver?